# how to set the translated data as a value to another component using ngx-translate

Tags: html, npm, angular5

I have two components : Appcomponent and LabelComponent 
Need to set the translated value based on the language json file

label.component.html:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!hideItem">
  <label [ngClass]="class">
    <ng-container *ngIf="hyperlink; else noLink">
       <a [routerLink]="url">{{labelValue}}</a>
    </ng-container>
  <ng-template #noLink>
    {{labelValue}}
  </ng-template>
  </label>
  </ng-container>
```

app.component.html:

```
<div class="row ">
  <div class="col-xl-2">

    <a-label [labelValue]="'lbl_status' | translate"></a-label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xl-4">
     <a-drop-down [placeholder]="''" name="status" [dataReader]="'status'" [fieldLabel]="''" 
    [httpUrl]="'dropdown' |  translate" [httpMethod]="'get'" 
    [displayField]="'value'" [valueField]="'code'" [width]="'150px'" [defaultValue]="'new'" >
     </a-drop-down>
</div>
</div>
```

The translated the value of 'lbl_status' | translate is showing in the web page but not binded with [labelValue]  so I can't get the value in label.componen.ts
@Input()labelValue : string;

same as the value of the 'dropdown' |  translate also not set to the [httpUrl]. I don't know this is lazy loading or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the ngOnChanges(){} method inside the component and add the lines same as ngOnInit(){}